# existence of an element in two List

Tags: java, swing

I want to verify the existence of an element in two JTable that displays questions
The program is when I click on a question in the first list it will be transferred to the second JTable but I do not want to add duplication restrictions so I did not want an issue to be added twice in the second list I want make an added control if it will add the user can not add the second time

```
table = new JTable();
    table.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < questions2.size(); i++) {
            /* the control code */  
                Question selected=questions.get(table.getSelectedRow());
                questions2.add(selected);
                questions.remove(selected);
                initDataBindings();
            } 


        }
    });
```

[My Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TOFrP.png)

[I do not want this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dwyfd.png)

Comment: take a look at: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html

Comment: if you don't want duplicate use `Set` not `list`. the only difference between the `set` and `List` is `List` contains duplicate but `set` never contains duplicate

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but i want to do a control of the JTable this is what i have to do in this exemple i must check the list and if the question exist i must show message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since you are using Jtables in the question,
you need to check if the value exists in the jtable first if the value doesnt exist then you can add it to the jtable. in the code you have submitted you are not checking if the value exists.

```
    public boolean ifExists(JTable table,string entry) {


    int rowCount = table.getRowCount();
    int columnCount = table.getColumnCount();


    for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
        String value = "";
        for (int j = 0; j < columnCount; j++)
            value = value + " " + table.getValueAt(i, j).toString();
        if (value.equalsIgnoreCase(entry)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

in the above code im checking the existence of the data using a for loop.
it will iterate over the jtable and return true if the value exist.
if the return value is false then you can go on and add the data. try it with the above code.

Comment: Thanks @Priyamal for the solution but the first JTable is displaying all the Question From the DataBase so i don't have to check the existance of the value you understand me?

Comment: if you dont want to add duplicates , then this is the way that you are supposed to do it.since you are trying to add data to a jtable without duplicates check the existence with this method you dont have to call it on every jtable try it on  the one you dont want the duplicates.

Comment: I don't want to check the duplicates into the first JTable i just want to check if the user want to add a question into the second JTable (beceause the first he can't do anything with it it display from DataBase) i want that the program check if the question exist into the second JTable show message("impossible to add it beacuse the question is already existing") if not he can add simply

Comment: Thanks a lot friend it's just a misunderstood thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Use Set. Lets say you have a first List:

```
List<Question> questions1 = new ArrayList<Question>();
```

now, Question must have this methods:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
     // Let your IDE generates it based on variables
}

@Override
public boolean equals() {
     // Let your IDE generates it based on variables
}
```

With this method, `Set` will be able to figure out if two `Question` are `equal`, and create `hashCode`, needed for storing. Best way is if you have unique `id`, but other stuff can help to. If you add `Question` class to your Answer, I might help you decide the best implementation of `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods.

Now, you place them in `HashSet`, as Users does some action:

```
HashSet<Question> questionsSet = new HashSet<Question>();
boolean isPresentInList = questionsSet.contains(question);
questionsSet.add(question);
```

Method contains will check if that question is present in `questionsSet`. `add` will check if there is an equal question in it, defined by rules in `equals()` method, and if it is, it will override it, else it will just add. In this way, you will not have duplicates in `questionsSet`.
Now, when you need an arrayList from `questionsSet` do this:

```
List<Question> questions2 = Arrays.asList(questionsSet);
```

Comment: Thanks but the hashCode and equals are done for List<Question> questions1 = new ArrayList<Question>(); (the first list) ?

Comment: Can you show me the code for Question? do you have those methods in it?

Comment: I have a set of service relating to  Question but in this case it's a simple display (Select Q From Question; i'm using JPQL)

Comment: But did you create class Question or?

Comment: I' cant do a check with FOR who course the second list and if the question exist in the second list it show a message of ("it exist) something like this

Comment: for is slow, works in O(n) and Set works in O(1). Also, remove from ArrayList costs, since you have to move all elements after that element, and that also takes time + it costs in memory, etc. So, its better to work with Set rather then with Array in order to check if something exists or not in it.

Comment: I generate hashCode and equals into class Question and then i put the firt part of the who you write it when i click on the first JTable(public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) { )

Comment: Sorry but with Set i can't use Bindings

Comment: what do you do here: initDataBindings?

Comment: I'm using Bindings to display from DataBase